# Best way to update/delete records in db based on Apache Kafka topic message

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, confluent-platform, snowflake-schema

I have an application publishing messages on a Kafka Topic. I've used Confluent's Snow Sync to synchronize the topic with a Snowflake table so when I publish a message to the topic it gets inserted in the table.

Each time a insert/update/delete operation is done from my app I'm inserting into our database but I also need to keep it in sync with Snowflake and we're planning to use Kafka topics for this. (we want to avoid Confluent's connectors to not create dependencies).

To summarize I'm sending a message that holds records information. And it should be inserted/ updated/ deleted. Insert is easy to handle using Snow Sync. What's the best practice to handle the other 2 operations? I'm mentioning that the data volume is going to be very large.

Comment: Hey Radu, am I understanding right, that you're looking for a reference implementation of a CDC sink?

If so, here is an example implementation how to deal with different record types (inserts, updates and deletes) using Snowflake  MERGE INTO: https://github.com/dariocazas/howto-debezium-to-snowflake/blob/main/snowflake/sql/01-cdc-to-replica-mysql.sql#L80-L127

Surely it needs to be adapted to your specific requirements.

Comment: Hello Anton. I need to achieve CDC but not the traditional way (log based or query based). What I want to do is to publish a message to Apache Kafka and then to be consumed by Snowflake. Using Snowflake Sync I was able to sync the inserts but don't know the best way to do handle delete/ update.

Comment: What is "Snowflake Sync"? Never heard of it.
Also not sure what you mean by "not traditional way" - CDC IS producing messages (or records, to be more precise) to be consumed by a down-stream system. What are you using to produce those "messages" and what's their structure?

Comment: Sorry, meant "Snowflake Sink". It's a connector offered by Confluent for Snowflake.
I have an application and each time it runs a sql command insert/update/delete on our Oracle Database a message is published to a Kafka topic with record details (haven't decide yet but let's say it's json or csv). My goal is to run that insert/update/delete also on Snowflake db.

Comment: Let's say that I have table A and topic t_a. When my app is inserting/updating/deleting on table A on Oracle DB I'm also sending a message with that record to t_a. Then Snowflake must match the db opeartions performed on table A of Oracle to Snowflake using info sent in t_a topic. I have an idea using triggers but I'm looking for best practice as Snowflake doesn't provide a native solution.

Comment: So you're literally building CDC on your own ;)
The link that I shared with you above is using a Snowflake Stream on a table (in your case that would be the Connector Target / line 30 ) and running a task for newly arrived records. The type of the operation is part of the record (see line 95), the actual handling is starting in line 115 for deletes, and line 117 for updates.

Comment: If you would like to get some inspiration on how such events might look like, have a look here: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-update-events or simply use the Debezium Oracle connector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the approach I've decided to follow. I'm leaving the url to the article here in case someone else needs to do something similar:
[Data materialization in Snowflake using Confluent Kafka](https://medium.com/hashmapinc/data-materialization-in-snowflake-using-confluent-kafka-connect-part-2-e19d86ca5abe)